# Compiled python script with py2exe for registering an excel add-in does not work

Tags: python, registry, py2exe, win32com, excel-addins

My objective is to made a sort of installer in order to register an Office Add-in written in Python. So, I started with the demo found into the Python folder (Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\excelAddin.py). The script works, the button and the messagebox appear. Then I used py2exe in order to deploy it and create an executable which do the same things. But in this way it doesn't work, I mean: after I run the exe, the button does not appear into the Excel bar. After some research I found that there are some differences on how the keys are registered into the Windows Registry. The executable does NOT registry the following keys:

xxxxx is the CLSID of the application

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\
```

In fact, when I run directly the excelAddin.py script I obtain this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.Addin
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Debugging\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\ProgID\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.ExcelAddin
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOM\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - excelAddin.ExcelAddin
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPolicy\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - win32com.server.policy.EventHandlerPolicy

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.Addin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Debugging\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\ProgID\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.ExcelAddin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOM\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - excelAddin.ExcelAddin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPolicy\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - win32com.server.policy.EventHandlerPolicy

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.Addin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\Debugging\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\Implemented Categories\{B3EF80D0-68E2-11D0-A689-00C04FD658FF}\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - pythoncomloader27.dll
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\InprocServer32\ --> Threading Model - REG_SZ - both
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\ProgID\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - Python.Test.ExcelAddin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOM\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - excelAddin.ExcelAddin
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPath\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32com\demos\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\xxxxx\PythonCOMPolicy\ --> (Standard) - REG_SZ - win32com.server.policy.EventHandlerPolicy
```

There are other several keys which I don't show here because they correctly match. I suppose the problem is in the fact that from the executable there is no way to register the script, or maybe the compiled script ".pyc". But even if I know this fact I am not able to figure out how to solve the problem. Does anyone else faced this kind of problem? Thank you

Other info:

- Python 2.7.6 32bit
- Windows 7 Professional
- Office 2010
- Link to the original script [excelAddin.py](http://pywin32.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywin32/pywin32/com/win32com/demos/excelAddin.py?view=markup)

This is the setup.py I wrote. Without admin privileges it does not work at all. I tried also with the option "console=" instead of "windows=" without success.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=[{
    'script': "excelAddin.py",
    'uac_info': "requireAdministrator",
},])
```

Comment: Put some error checking into your installer and make it a py2exe `console=` application so you can easily see any error messages printed to stdout and stderr.

Comment: have you tried using an alternative such as cx_freeze?

Comment: @Temere thank you, I tried cx_freeze, I notice it permits to do less job for what concern admin privileges and library imports, but does not solve the above problem

Comment: @martineau thank you, I did it, the only thing that I can notice is the fact that the register.py module of win32com cannot get correctly the script path (scriptDir and addnPath variables) because after deploying actually there is not a script anymore. Unfortunately, the time is not so much for me to continue trying in this way, now I am doing the same thing with C# and VSTO...